# Is it possible to put Safari 4's tabs on top of the window?

Tags: macos, safari

In the Safari 4 betas, the tab bar was moved to the top of the window, rather than underneath the address/bookmark bar:

[image: Safari 4 Beta's tabs]

Is there any way to get this back in the current Safari 4.0.3 (non-beta release)?

I can only find the command to disable this feature in the betas:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari DebugSafari4TabBarIsOnTop -bool NO
```

Changing `NO` to `YES` has no effect with the current version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, but it requires some hacking. **You need to have the beta installer**.

1. Install Safari 4 final
2. Using [pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) extract *only* the Safari application from the beta installer.
3. Replace the final Safari.app with the beta Safari.app - do not replace any system files!
4. You should be able to launch the application now, using the new safari system files and the beta application (with tabs on top etc.)

Here is a link to a guide:

[MacOSX Hints with some basic info](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20090609000156651), see the comments for more details

The article references [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/), an application which allows you to work with installer .pkg files. While it is paid the demo should be enough to complete the changes needed.

You should probably keep a copy of the application somewhere, as any Safari update will overwrite it again.

Answer (score 2):

No. The design choice was reversed. None of the beta settings apply to the final.

Answer (score -1):

It is not changing YES to NO or vice versa, it is changing them to FALSE or TRUE, vice versa.

http://lifehacker.com/5161005/put-safari-4-betas-tabs-back

Comment: `defaults write` treats both YES and TRUE the same, if you do `defaults read com.apple.Safari DebugSafari4TabBarIsOnTop` after either, it returns `1` (but neither works)